# $gte and $lte not working properly in mongodb version 3.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents in the following structure saved in my mongodb `version 3.40`

test

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548905"),
    "userId" : "2",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-20 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-20 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 10
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548904"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-20 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-20 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 10
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548903"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 55
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548902"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 84
}
```

Now i want to fetch the results like `gte` & `lte` i had written the query but it not working properly.means i am not getting my expected output.

I am getting below output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548902"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 84
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548903"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 55
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548902"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 84
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548903"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 55
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548904"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-20 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-20 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 10
}
```

My Code

```
 db.test.aggregate([
  { "$match": 
    {
    'userId' : { $in : ['1']},
    'startTime': {$gte: '2019-03-19' },
    'endTime': {$lte: '2019-03-20' }
    }
  }
])
```

I have searched so many times but i am getting answer, kindly anyone help me out on this, if possible post your answer here

Updated Code but not working

```
db.test.aggregate([
   { 
     $match: {
          $and: [ 
              {userId: {$in: ["1"]}},
              { $or : [ { startTime : { $gte : '2019-03-19' } }, { endTime : { $lt : '2019-03-19' } } ] }
          ]
     }
   }
  ])
```

expected output I should not get `2019-03-20`

Getting Output

```
/* 1 createdAt:6/18/2019, 2:53:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548902"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 84
},

/* 2 createdAt:6/18/2019, 2:53:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548903"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-19 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-19 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 55
},

/* 3 createdAt:6/18/2019, 2:53:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ad7ed510022ebc548904"),
    "userId" : "1",
    "startTime" : "2019-03-20 17:52:25",
    "endTime" : "2019-03-20 17:53:49",
    "loginTime" : 10
}
```

Comment: Could you show the query ?

Comment: I posted my code

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: I have tried but not getting my expected answer, can you please any one post your answer

Comment: is time saved as string or date object?

Comment: @ tom slabbaert, String

Comment: `$lte` not working my code, because `2019-03-20` record not fetching

Comment: Your two approaches are not comparable. In one you want the record from 03-20, in the other you don't.

Comment: And it's quite clear why both of the snippets give the results that they do. First one: because `"2019-03-20 17:52:25"` is greater than `"2019-03-20"`. Second one: because of the `$or`. Only one condition needs to match for document to be included, and it's the `$gte : '2019-03-19'`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, Point NO 1 => startTime = 2019-03-19 & endTime = 2019-03-20 so i need upto `2019-03-20` this records

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, Point NO 2 => startTime = 2019-03-19 & endTime = 2019-03-19 so i need upto `2019-03-19` this records only i need to fetch

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, can you please post your answer

Answer (score 1):

(*posting comment as an answer, as requested*)

Here's why your two approaches fail to produce your expected results.

The first one does not return document from "2019-03-20 17:52:25" because that string is greater lexicographically (that is, not `$lte`) than "2019-03-20" and therefore is filtered out.

Second one: because of the `$or`. Only one condition needs to match for document to be included, and it's the `$gte: '2019-03-19'`. That's why you get a record from 2019-03-20 (because it satisfies that clause).

And storing datetimes as strings is generally a bad idea. It takes up more space and you can't use datetime functions (like extract day/month/year/etc.). Not to mention that correct ordering is heavily dependent on format used. If it's not a ISO-8601-ish format, it likely won't sort correctly.

Comment: I believe that these hints are sufficient to help OP arrive to needed changes.